# SMTP errors at sending emails with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to send some test newsletter using my gmail account as smtp, but when i tried to send to multiple recipients - **['emai@laddr@email.com, emailaddr2@email.com']** - in this case the first email address is incorrect - it gives me an error **555 - 5.5.2 Syntax error** and the process stops without passing through the next email addreses.

My question is:
**is there a possibility to bypass those kind of errors in order to skip the incorrect addresses and to continue sending the emails?**

Answer (score 1):

You can set [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) to ignore delivery errors, but that's not really considered best practice in a production environment.

```
# environment.rb (or development/test etc)
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

If you don't have a lot of recipients, you could try looping through the array of addresses and sending an email for each one, rescuing a delivery error and adding a message to the log.

```
# Model
def send_emails(addresses)
  addresses.each do |address|
    begin
      YourMailer.deliver_method(email)
    rescue
      logger.error "Could not send email to #{email}" 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i've tried setting raise_delivery_errors=false without luck. I tend to think that the problem here is with smtp_tls stopping the process but i do not know for sure.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you try my second suggestion?